2016 Fiesta pops out of reverse gear
I have a 2016 manual transmission Ford Fiesta EcoBoost Zetec and often, when starting to reverse I'll think I've placed it properly into gear but, as I come off the clutch and power on it'll lurch backwards and pop out of gear (but the lever won't return all the way to neutral position) making a loud grinding noise as if I'd shifted without clutching or matching revs.
Sometimes the car will actually briefly reverse properly rather than just lurching, so the gears do seem to (sometimes) bite.
Additionally if I continue to apply pressure to the lever whilst the reversing this issue doesn't occur.
This occurs both when shifting from first (having reached a complete stop) and from neutral, including when first starting the car for the day.
The issue has been present since I got the car a couple of years ago but, pardon the pun, is really starting to grind my gears (especially as the place I usually park it involves having to parallel park up a fairly steep hill).
What is likely to be needed to get the reverse gear to sit comfortably like the other gears, and how much (ballpark) is it likely to cost (in the North of England)?
I note this question where the answer seems to suggest a potential reason, but not a way to fix it which is the purpose of this question.
